# SOQL custom string in Column list

Tags: soql

I am running the query

```
SELECT Id, BodyLength, Body, Description FROM Attachment WHERE SystemModStamp <= 2015-08-27T15:48:25.403Z
```

and storing the response in SOAP API.

I need to ignore the body field and write it as a custom path at which the file will be stored. Like:

```
SELECT Id, BodyLength, 'customPath' + Id + '_' + FileName,  Description FROM Attachment WHERE SystemModStamp <= 2015-08-27T15:48:25.403Z
```

Is this possible? Dev console returned error. If not, what are the other ways that I can achieve this using SOQL?

Comment: Not possible. You will need to do the query and then build the response as required